# Manage Existing Extensions empty in Magento Connect Manager

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to update some extensions using Magento Connect Manager but whenever I go to Magento Connect Manager, I get an empty table for **Manage Existing Extensions**.

I managed the file permissions as well, so all the directories are now writable. But somehow the table where it would list all the Magento extensions are empty. I have been told there were some rough measures taken while updating Magento earlier, this should be the reason for such an issue.

Below are the list of actions I've tried

1. File permission has been changed to 777 to all folders
2. Cleared all the caches, reindexing is also done

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Did you find any better solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

please check the var/package folder.this error can be because missing of that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Via command Line run:

```
 ./mage mage-setup .
 ./mage sync
 ./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

This should show all module installed on Magento on the Manage Existing Extensions table - BUT remember this will upgrade the modules to the latest version